# Javascript: how to map array and split string content to new cell

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Which code should I use on js to map an array with spliting cells yet not reapeating `["12,3","3","5","66,22"]` into `["12","3","5","66","22"]`.

Comment: This is not a place where you can ask us to write code for you. First tell us what you have tried and if you tried what issue you are facing. Please go through what kind of questions you can ask [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

You could join and split the string.

```js
console.log(["12,3", "3", "5", "66,22"].join().split(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you miss one `3` element in your desired output, if so - try following solution:

```js
var arr = ["12,3","3","5","66,22"],
    res = [].concat(...arr.map(v => v.split(',')));
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: He says 'not reapeating' so he probably wants the result to be unique. I guess you could use a Set to do that easily `res = Array.from([...new Set(res)])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ES6 way to get the desired output

```
x = ["12,3","3","5","66,22"];
y = [];
for (i of x){
  y = [...y, ...(i.split(","))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To throw another onto the pile:

```js
   a = Array.from([...new Set(["12,3", "3", "5", "66,22"].flatMap(x=>x.split(",")))])
console.log(a)
```

if uniqueness wasn't required, then just doing flatMap to the input would be enough