# Create new array in which items with commas are separated into unique items in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is combining the sources of multiple arrays using `concat`.

```
var tags = [].concat.apply([], [typeArr,genderArr,conditionArr]);
```

The items in the array are then filtered for any

```
  tags = tags.filter(function(entry) { return entry.trim() != ''; });
```

However, I realized that, because of where the data comes from, some items are coming in as strings with commas, such that `tags` array looks like the following: `["red","blue","green,yellow,orange","purple,black"]`

How could I split the items so that the tags array looks like `["red","blue","green","yellow","orange","purple","black"]`? I was thinking something where I loop over the array and then use split to reinsert these into a new array?

I'm trying to do it with vanilla JavaScript

Comment: "I was thinking something where I loop over the array and then use split to reinsert these into a new array". Sounds like good thinking. Have you tried it? What seems to not be working here that this post exists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42391430/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43528397/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) by comma (or `.toString()` which does the same) to convert the array to a single string, the use [`Array.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by comma to get an array of individual items:

```js
var arr = ["red","blue","green,yellow,orange","purple,black"];

var result = arr.join(',').split(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can use `join()`, since the default is a comma.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting *unique values* after the [values have been separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391430/concat-array-into-one-array-js-or-lodash).

```js
var array = ["red", "blue", "green,yellow,orange", "purple,black", "green,red"],
    result = Array.from(new Set(array.join(',').split(',')));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = ["red","blue","green,yellow,orange","purple,black"];

data = data.reduce(function(prev, next) {
    return prev.concat(next.split(','));
}, []);

console.log(data);
```